# Adding a column thats result of difference of rows and shift in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, difference

Lets say I have a dataframe like this

| Column A |
| --- |
| a |
| b |
| c |
| d |
| e |
| f |

a,b,c,d,e,f are values. I need to be able to add a column to the orignal dataframe which is got by computing the differences of rows.

So i need something like this

| Column A | New |
| --- | --- |
| a | b-a |
| b | 0 |
| c | d-c |
| d | 0 |
| e | f-e |
| f | 0 |

I saw something called diff on the dataframe/series but that does it slightly differently as in first element will become Nan

Comment: use diff but in reverse order, then replace odd numbered indexes with 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
import numpy as np

df['New'] = df['Column A'].diff(-1).mul(-1).mask(np.arange(len(df))%2==1, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.shift(-1)`

```
df['New'] = df['Column A'].shift(-1) - df['Column A']
df.loc[df.index % 2 == 1, 'New'] = 0
```

Comment: WoW! Thanks for the insight. I was trying to implement this df.index % 2 == 1 logic.